# Is there a way to convert a DateTimeOffset into minutes since midnight?

Tags: c#, .net, datetimeoffset

Is there a way to convert a `DateTimeOffset` into minutes since midnight?

I want the offset part to be reflected in the answer it gives.

Comment: since midnight of the day its pointing to?

Answer (score 8):

```
dateTimeOffset.UtcDateTime.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes
```

returns the number of minutes since midnight for the original date/time from which the offset was subtracted

so if date/time = Jan 2 2013 and offset =8 hours, this will return 16 hours (since Jan 1 midnight)

Comment: But what about The TimeOfDay property is not affected by the value of the Offset property as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.datetimeoffset.timeofday.aspx . Does this not mean that the minutes could be wrong?

Comment: @AJM, please try the new code (keep in mind the offset is subtracted from the date)

Comment: Actually, your first version was correct.  This will return midnight at UTC.  The other will return midnight in the offset you started with.  The MSDN doc means that the offset is not re-applied, which is how you want it.

Comment: One other thing to be aware, if you are in a time zone that changes offsets due to daylight savings time, this will technically be wrong on the transition days.  You can't get a true correct midnight for those dates without knowing also a time zone id.